# VelocityJS: use stagger with custom sequence

Tags: sequence, velocity.js

I'm trying to apply a stagger option to a custom velocity sequence.
In my example, I'm using the sequence from the documentation to simplify.

**The sequence**

```
$.Velocity.Sequences.mySequence = function (element, options) {
    var duration = options.duration || 750;
    $.Velocity.animate(element,
        { 
            translateY: "-=10px",
        }, { 
            delay: duration * 0.033,
            duration: duration,
            loop: 3,
            easing: "easeInOutSine"
        });
};
```

**The call (failing)**

```
$("div").velocity('mySequence', { stagger: 200 });
```

**The call (succeeding)**

Stagger is occurring when I use any predefined sequence from the UI Pack.

```
$("div").velocity('callout.bounce', { stagger: 200 });
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/griable/pen/ncsmC

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Nope. I ended up using on of the default animations. I've never used velocity again but it seems like the behaviour has changed.

Have a look to the Plugins: UI Pack section on http://julian.com/research/velocity/. Good luck!